# Как увеличить видео миниатюру при клике

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ребят есть баннер при клике открывается модальное окно , в контенте Три миниатюры с бекграундом и заложено туда видео , как сделать чтобы при клике на миниатюру всплывал popup окно и воспроизводилось видео?? на чистом js HTML

***HTML***

```
    <!-- Ссылки на вызов модальных окон-->
<a href="#win1" class="button-image"><img src="images/banner.png"/></a>
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="win1"></a>
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="content">
          <a class="close"title="Закрыть" href="#close" id="winclose"></a>
            <div id="custom_links" class="custom-links">
                <a href="#" class="custom_links app-store" title="App Store"></a>
                <a href="#" class="custom_links google-play" title="Google Play"></a>
                <a href="#" class="custom_links main-cta" title="CIBC MODERN LIFE"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="video-box-wrapper-0" id="myImg0">
                <div class="video-trigger">
                    <video>some video</video>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="video-box-wrapper-1" id="myImg1">
                <div class="video-trigger">
                    <video>some video</video>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="video-box-wrapper-2" id="myImg2">
                <div class="video-trigger">
                    <video>some video</video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

***CSS***

```
 .button-image{
    float: right;
}
/* Базовые стили слоя затемнения и модального окна  */
.overlay {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    /* фон затемнения */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    position: fixed; /* фиксированное поцизионирование */
    cursor: default; /* тип курсара */
}
/* активируем слой затемнения */
.overlay:target {
    display: block;
}
/* стили модального окна */
.popup {
    right: 0;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 1030px;
    height: 640px;
    top:0;
    /* фиксированное позиционирование, окно стабильно при прокрутке */
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid #383838;
    background: #fefefe;

    /* внешняя тень */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
}
/* активируем модальный блок */
.overlay:target+.popup {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    top: 10px;
}
/* формируем кнопку закрытия */
.close {
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 13px/20px 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .8s;
    transition: all ease .8s;
}
.close:before {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    content: "X";
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    font-size: 12px;
}
.close:hover {
    background-color: rgba(252, 20, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
/* изображения внутри окна */
.popup img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
/* элементы м-медиа, фреймы */
.popup embed,
.popup iframe {
    top: 15px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
}
.popup h2 { /* заголовок 2 */
    margin: 0;
    color: #008000;
    padding: 5px 0px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #adadad;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-family: 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
/* параграфы */
.popup p {margin: 0; padding: 5px 0}
/*content*/
.content{
    width: 1030px;
    height: 640px;
    background: url("images/main-background.jpg") no-repeat;
}
.custom_links{
    display: block;
}
.app-store{
    background-image: url("images/app-store.png");
    position: absolute;
    width: 124px;
    height: 37px;
    left:435px;
    bottom:177px;
}
.google-play{
    background-image: url("images/google-play-fr.png");
    position: absolute;
    width: 109px;
    height: 37px;
    right: 332px;
    bottom: 177px;
}
.main-cta{
    background-image: url("images/main-cta.png");
    width: 178px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 57px;
    bottom:32px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.app-store, .google-play{
    z-index: 10;
}
.video-box-wrapper-0{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.video-trigger{
    display: block;
    transition: transform .2s ease;
 }
.video-box-wrapper-0 .video-trigger{
    width:216px;
    height:121px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    right: 57px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    display: block;
    background:url("images/prev-video-etrans_en.jpg") no-repeat;
    top:65px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.vd-box{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1999;
    display: none;
}
.video-box-wrapper-1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.video-box-wrapper-1 .video-trigger{
    width:216px;
    height:121px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    right: 57px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    display: block;
    background:url("images/prev-video-dao_en.jpg") no-repeat;
    top:203px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.video-box-wrapper-2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.video-box-wrapper-2 .video-trigger{
    width:216px;
    height:121px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    right: 57px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    display: block;
    background:url("images/prev-video-goldfish_en.jpg") no-repeat;
    top:341px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.video-trigger:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.video-trigger::after{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    top:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-image: url("images/video-play.png");
}
```

Comment: А изначально в окне какая-то миниатюра должна быть активна?

Comment: @Cheg нет не должна быть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Решение не моё**

```js
var preview = document.querySelector('.preview'),
  video = document.querySelector('#video'),
  modal = document.querySelector('.modal'),
  modalClose = document.querySelector('.modal-close');

preview.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  modal.classList.add('modal-visible');
  video.play();
}
modalClose.onclick = function() {  
  modal.classList.remove('modal-visible');
  video.pause(); 
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.preview {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.preview:hover {
  background: #777;
  color: #fff;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1999;
  display: none;
}

.modal-inner {
  width: 80%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.video-responsive {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-responsive > video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ccc;
  z-index: 1;
  border: none;
}
.modal-close:hover {
  background: #f00;
}

.modal-visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <a href="#" class="preview">
  Preview
</a>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-inner">
    <div class="video-responsive">
      <video id="video" controls loop>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"> Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
    </div>
    <button class="modal-close" title="Close">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а можно в моем примере показать

Comment: мне лень.. дело не сложное

Comment: @Anton Есть такая либа `fancybox`, там уже все за тебя сделано. с Видео тоже.http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/

Comment: @Tsyklop насколько понимаю, ТСу нужно, что видео открывалось не в новом попапе, а в том, где миниатюры расположены.

Comment: @Tsyklop нужно на чистом js без jquery